# In asp.net. when i run my program i have an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'initialcatalog'.
>   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable
>   parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable
>   synonyms, Boolean firstKey) at
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString,
>   Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String
>   connectionString) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String
>   connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions&
>   userConnectionOptions) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
>   at WebApplication59.WebForm1.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   in c:\Users\rishabhgupta\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\WebApplication59\WebApplication59\WebForm1.aspx.cs:line
>   50

Comment: Please show us the entire connection string.  You can replace the user name and password with "XXXXX", we don't need to know what those are.

Comment: Yeah I get exceptions too. Bummer, eh?

Answer (score 2):

`initialcatalog` should be two words:  `Initial Catalog`.